# Are these two method calls the same?

Tags: java

Code blocks number 1.

```
public class SomeClass {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        SomeClass foo = new SomeClass();
        foo.SomeMethod();
    }
    public void SomeMethod() {

    }
}
```

Code blocks number 2.

```
public class SomeClass {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
       new SomeClass().SomeMethod();
    }
    public void SomeMethod() {

    }
}
```

Are this two code blocks(number 1 and 2) the same? I'm confused over the different syntax during calling the method. I appreciate if someone could explain it for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, they are functionally the same. With code block 2, however, you have no way of accessing the `SomeClass` object you created in the future lifespan of the program.

Comment: There's no way to access it in the future in either case; foo is being discarded.

Answer (score 1):

Yes they are same.  In first case the object reference is just stored in a reference variable for future usage .
In second case the reference is not stored.